# html2canvas file makes images distorted when they are cropped

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas

I want to upload an image, then crop it, and then preview it on my website, it works, but when I use html2canvas to download the canvas, the cropped image gets distorted.

CSS:

```
#uploadedImage{
    position: absolute;
    height: 344px;
    width: 191px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
const myElement = document.getElementById('frameContainer');
function imageDownload() {
  myElement.style.borderRadius = 0;
  html2canvas(myElement).then(canvas => {
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = 'image.jpg';
  link.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  }).catch(error => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you make a runnable snippet with an image we can use. I suspect that cover isn’t being dealt with correctly but don’t know for sure without trying it.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, used background instead of image.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).